# tf vesion problem. Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the code that create problem.

```
def cost_func(x=None, y=None):
   
    if not x:
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
    if not y:
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

    # two local minima near (0, 0)
    #     z = __f1(x, y)

    # 3rd local minimum at (-0.5, -0.8)
    z = -1 * __f2(x, y, x_mean=-0.5, y_mean=-0.8, x_sig=0.35, y_sig=0.35)

    # one steep gaussian trench at (0, 0)
    #     z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=0, y_mean=0, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)

    # three steep gaussian trenches
    z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=1.0, y_mean=-0.5, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)
    z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=-1.0, y_mean=0.5, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)
    z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=-0.5, y_mean=-0.8, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)

    return x, y, z
```

My goal is:

```
    For visualizing contour plot, call f() and collect placeholder nodes for fast GPU calc.
    To incorporate variables to optimize, pass them in as argument to attach as x and y.

    Args:
        x: None if placeholder tensor is used as input. Specify x to use x as input tensor.
        y: None if placeholder tensor is used as input. Specify y to use y as input tensor.

    Returns:
        Tuple (x, y, z) where x and y are input tensors and z is output tensor.
```

The error is:
using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

The fully code is:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
# cost function
def cost_func(x=None, y=None):
    '''Cost function.
    For visualizing contour plot, call f() and collect placeholder nodes for fast GPU calc.
    To incorporate variables to optimize, pass them in as argument to attach as x and y.

    Args:
        x: None if placeholder tensor is used as input. Specify x to use x as input tensor.
        y: None if placeholder tensor is used as input. Specify y to use y as input tensor.

    Returns:
        Tuple (x, y, z) where x and y are input tensors and z is output tensor.
    '''

    if not x:
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
    if not y:
        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

    # two local minima near (0, 0)
    #     z = __f1(x, y)

    # 3rd local minimum at (-0.5, -0.8)
    z = -1 * __f2(x, y, x_mean=-0.5, y_mean=-0.8, x_sig=0.35, y_sig=0.35)

    # one steep gaussian trench at (0, 0)
    #     z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=0, y_mean=0, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)

    # three steep gaussian trenches
    z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=1.0, y_mean=-0.5, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)
    z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=-1.0, y_mean=0.5, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)
    z -= __f2(x, y, x_mean=-0.5, y_mean=-0.8, x_sig=0.2, y_sig=0.2)

    return x, y, z


# noisy hills of the cost function
def __f1(x, y):
    return -1 * tf.sin(x * x) * tf.cos(3 * y * y) * tf.exp(-(x * y) * (x * y)) - tf.exp(-(x + y) * (x + y))


# bivar gaussian hills of the cost function
def __f2(x, y, x_mean, y_mean, x_sig, y_sig):
    normalizing = 1 / (2 * np.pi * x_sig * y_sig)
    x_exp = (-1 * tf.square(x - x_mean)) / (2 * tf.square(x_sig))
    y_exp = (-1 * tf.square(y - y_mean)) / (2 * tf.square(y_sig))
    return normalizing * tf.exp(x_exp + y_exp)


# pyplot settings
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
params = {'legend.fontsize': 3,
          'legend.handlelength': 3}
plt.rcParams.update(params)
plt.axis('off')

# input (x, y) and output (z) nodes of cost-function graph
x, y, z = cost_func()

# visualize cost function as a contour plot
x_val = y_val = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.005, dtype=np.float32)
x_val_mesh, y_val_mesh = np.meshgrid(x_val, y_val)
x_val_mesh_flat = x_val_mesh.reshape([-1, 1])
y_val_mesh_flat = y_val_mesh.reshape([-1, 1])
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    z_val_mesh_flat = sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: x_val_mesh_flat, y: y_val_mesh_flat})
z_val_mesh = z_val_mesh_flat.reshape(x_val_mesh.shape)
levels = np.arange(-10, 1, 0.05)
# ax.contour(x_val_mesh, y_val_mesh, z_val_mesh, levels, alpha=.7, linewidths=0.4)
# ax.plot_wireframe(x_val_mesh, y_val_mesh, z_val_mesh, alpha=.5, linewidths=0.4, antialiased=True)
ax.plot_surface(x_val_mesh, y_val_mesh, z_val_mesh, alpha=.4, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
plt.draw()

# starting location for variables
x_i = 0.75
y_i = 1.0

# create variable pair (x, y) for each optimizer
x_var, y_var = [], []
for i in range(7):
    x_var.append(tf.Variable(x_i, [1], dtype=tf.float32))
    y_var.append(tf.Variable(y_i, [1], dtype=tf.float32))

# create separate graph for each variable pairs
cost = []
for i in range(7):
    cost.append(cost_func(x_var[i], y_var[i])[2])

# define method of gradient descent for each graph
# optimizer label name, learning rate, color
ops_param = np.array([['Adadelta', 50.0, 'b'],
                      ['Adagrad', 0.10, 'g'],
                      ['Adam', 0.05, 'r'],
                      ['Ftrl', 0.5, 'c'],
                      ['GD', 0.05, 'm'],
                      ['Momentum', 0.01, 'y'],
                      ['RMSProp', 0.02, 'k']])

ops = []
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(float(ops_param[0, 1])).minimize(cost[0]))
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradOptimizer(float(ops_param[1, 1])).minimize(cost[1]))
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(float(ops_param[2, 1])).minimize(cost[2]))
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.FtrlOptimizer(float(ops_param[3, 1])).minimize(cost[3]))
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(float(ops_param[4, 1])).minimize(cost[4]))
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.MomentumOptimizer(float(ops_param[5, 1]), momentum=0.95).minimize(cost[5]))
ops.append(tf.compat.v1.train.RMSPropOptimizer(float(ops_param[6, 1])).minimize(cost[6]))

# 3d plot camera zoom, angle
xlm = ax.get_xlim3d()
ylm = ax.get_ylim3d()
zlm = ax.get_zlim3d()
ax.set_xlim3d(xlm[0] * 0.5, xlm[1] * 0.5)
ax.set_ylim3d(ylm[0] * 0.5, ylm[1] * 0.5)
ax.set_zlim3d(zlm[0] * 0.5, zlm[1] * 0.5)
azm = ax.azim
ele = ax.elev + 40
ax.view_init(elev=ele, azim=azm)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # use last location to draw a line to the current location
    last_x, last_y, last_z = [], [], []
    plot_cache = [None for _ in range(len(ops))]

    # loop each step of the optimization algorithm
    steps = 1000
    for iter in range(steps):
        for i, op in enumerate(ops):
            # run a step of optimization and collect new x and y variable values
            _, x_val, y_val, z_val = sess.run([op, x_var[i], y_var[i], cost[i]])

            # move dot to the current value
            if plot_cache[i]:
                plot_cache[i].remove()
            plot_cache[i] = ax.scatter(x_val, y_val, z_val, s=3, depthshade=True, label=ops_param[i, 0],
                                       color=ops_param[i, 2])

            # draw a line from the previous value
            if iter == 0:
                last_z.append(z_val)
                last_x.append(x_i)
                last_y.append(y_i)
            ax.plot([last_x[i], x_val], [last_y[i], y_val], [last_z[i], z_val], linewidth=0.5, color=ops_param[i, 2])
            last_x[i] = x_val
            last_y[i] = y_val
            last_z[i] = z_val

        if iter == 0:
            legend = np.vstack((ops_param[:, 0], ops_param[:, 1])).transpose()
            plt.legend(plot_cache, legend)

        plt.savefig('figures/' + str(iter) + '.png')
        print('iteration: {}'.format(iter))

        plt.pause(0.0001)

print("done")
```

If x and y are placeholder tensor and they are used as input, output None. I have tried converting x and y to other types (such as string) if they are placeholder tensors, and then outputting them directly if they are not placeholder tensors. But I found that this didn't work. Then I tried not using keyword arguments, but making the determination within the function, and I found that that didn't work either.

As I understand, I will solve this problem if I use tensorflow v1, but I want to use tensorflow v2. Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, you can either use eager execution or decorate the function using @tf.function. Eager execution is enabled by default, so if you're using versions of TensorFlow older than 1.10.0, you may need to explicitly enable it in your code. To enable it, you can add the following line of code:
tf.enable_eager_execution()
The @tf.function decorator allows for the conversion of a Python function into a TensorFlow graph. It accepts parameters, such as input signature and autograph, that can be used to control how the graph is generated. For more information, you can refer to the official TensorFlow documentation